# scope variable inside HTML does not get its value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
HTML code:
<section ng-controller="GalleryController as gallery" >
  <div photo-directive ng-repeat="photo in gallery.photos" ng-if="$index>=50*counter && $index<50*(counter+1)"></div>
</section>
<script src="js/controller.js"></script>
```

and `controller.js:`

```
(function() {
  angular
    .module('myapp')  
    .controller('GalleryController', GalleryController);

  GalleryController.$inject = ['GalleryService'];

  function GalleryController(GalleryService){
     var self=this;
     self.counter=0;
  } 
})();
```

Do not worry about `gallery.photos and photo-directive`. My problem is that counter has no value when DOM is loaded instead of 0. **Why that**? And **how may I fix it** as to make it read the value from the controller?

Comment: you have to access it as `gallery.counter`, as you do not add the counter to the `$scope`, but to the Controller's `this`

Comment: Thank  you   very much mate

Answer (score 0):

Where is the **$scope** in the controller ? you need to add $scope.counter =0 inside the controller instead of **this** , anything attached to $scope can be read from the view .

Answer (score 0):

you can call counter with

```
 gallery.counter
```